# how to retrieve user responses from hero card using c#

Tags: c#, botframework

Need to get the value of hero card clicked through C#.

The code is below

```
IMessageActivity newPost = context.MakeMessage();
List<CardAction> cardButtons = new List<CardAction>();

CardAction SRButton = new CardAction()
{
    Value = "shared mailbox request",
    Type = "imBack",
    Title = "Create Share Mailbox Request"
}; 

CardAction priorityButton = new CardAction()
{
    Value = "show me priority tickets",
    Type = "imBack",
    Title = "Status on P1 & P2 Incidents"
};

cardButtons.Add(SRButton);                
HeroCard welcomeCard = new HeroCard()
{
    Title = "Hello, I'm your Virtual Assistant. How can I help you?",
    Subtitle = "You can type your request below or ask me about the following",
    Buttons = cardButtons
};              

newPost.Attachments.Add(welcomeCard.ToAttachment());
await context.PostAsync(newPost);
context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
context.Done(new object());
public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var message = await result;

    //InputValues data;
    await context.PostAsync(message);

    if (message.Value != null)
    {
        // Got an Action Submit
        dynamic value = message.Value;
        string submitType = value.Type.ToString();
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (submitType == "Incident")
            {
                var feedbackForm = new FormDialog<FeedbackForm>(new FeedbackForm(), FeedbackForm.BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, null);
                context.Call<FeedbackForm>(feedbackForm, FeedbackFormCompleteAsync);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

But getting exception ReplyToId cannot be null.
I'm doing this in V3, getting many examples of this same kind in nodejs. If anyone has done pls let me know.
Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're using v3? It is highly recommended that you migrate to v4: https://blog.botframework.com/2019/06/07/v3-bot-broadcast-message/

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Are you going to migrate to v4? Do you still want a solution in v3?